# No injection source found for a parameter of type public java.util.List

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, swagger, jersey-2.0

> org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.
>       [FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type public java.util.List

```
com.org.testing.controller.getSentInviteList(com.org.testing.domain.FriendshipInvitee$Status,com.org.testing.domain.ext.RequestBounds,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,org.springframework.security.core.Authentication) throws java.lang.IllegalAccessException,com.org.testing.exception.BusinessException at index 0.; source='ResourceMethod{httpMethod=POST, consumedTypes=[application/json], producedTypes=[application/json], suspended=false, suspendTimeout=0, suspendTimeoutUnit=MILLISECONDS, invocable=Invocable{handler=ClassBasedMethodHandler{handlerClass=class com.org.testing.controller, handlerConstructors=[org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.HandlerConstructor@190e93e3]}, definitionMethod=public java.util.List com.org.testing.controller.getSentInviteList(com.org.testing.domain.FriendshipInvitee$Status,com.org.testing.domain.ext.RequestBounds,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse,org.springframework.security.core.Authentication) throws java.lang.IllegalAccessException,com.org.testing.exception.BusinessException, parameters=[Parameter [type=class com.org.testing.domain.FriendshipInvitee$Status, source=status, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class com.org.testing.domain.ext.RequestBounds, source=null, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=interface javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse, source=null, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=interface org.springframework.security.core.Authentication, source=null, defaultValue=null]], responseType=java.util.List<com.org.testing.domain.LeaderboardInvitation>}, nameBindings=[]}']

    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.initialize(ApplicationHandler.java:467)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.access$500(ApplicationHandler.java:163)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler$3.run(ApplicationHandler.java:323)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:289)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$2.call(Errors.java:286)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.processWithException(Errors.java:286)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:320)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:285)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:311)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:170)
        at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:358)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1274)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1186)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1081)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:5033)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5320)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:901)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:877)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:633)
        at org.eclipse.gemini.web.tomcat.internal.TomcatServletContainer.startWebApplication(TomcatServletContainer.java:125)
        at org.eclipse.gemini.web.internal.StandardWebApplication.start(StandardWebApplication.java:109)
        at org.eclipse.virgo.web.core.internal.WebBundleLifecycleListener.onStarted(WebBundleLifecycleListener.java:122)
        at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.artifact.internal.StandardArtifactStateMonitor.onStarted(StandardArtifactStateMonitor.java:271)
        at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.artifact.internal.AbstractInstallArtifact.asyncStartSucceeded(AbstractInstallArtifact.java:319)
        at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.artifact.internal.AbstractInstallArtifact.access$0(AbstractInstallArtifact.java:316)
        at org.eclipse.virgo.kernel.install.artifact.internal.AbstractInstallArtifact$StateMonitorSignal.signalSuccessfulCompletion(AbstractInstallArtifact.java:252)
        at org.eclipse.virgo.nano.core.internal.BundleStartTracker$1.run(BundleStartTracker.java:140)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

I am having a spring-mvc restfull webservice project, I am quite new for Jersey and swagger. I have given my most efforts to create documentation for api's using swagger.but at last moments i saw some limitation of jersey with swagger.

I have covered most api's in documentation but there are following cases which is creating issue for documentation using swagger. Cases are listed below:-

1. If Endpoint have multiple input parameter (Request Params), Jersey uses only path params , it doesn’t support Request params.
2. If Response type is based on collection , then apis throwing exception.
3. If Request params have any collection type input parameter.

I am using spring 3.x framework in my project and i have added jersey 2.12 version and using swagger 1.0.

**I am looking for help to troubleshoot this error.**

Here is my code

```
@Path("/invite/sent/list")
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@ApiOperation(
        value = "get List", response=LBTest.class,
        responseContainer="List",
        notes = "API to get list.")
@ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "Successful retrieval of resource options"), @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal server error"), @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "Illegal Access of Resource") })
@RequestMapping(value = "/v2/lb/invite/sent/list", method = RequestMethod.POST)
@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
@ResponseBody
public List<LBTest> getSentInviteList(@ApiParam(value = "status", required = false) @RequestParam(value = "status", required = false) Invitee.Status status, @RequestBody RequestBounds requestBounds,
        @Context HttpServletResponse response, @Context Authentication auth) throws IllegalAccessException, BusinessException
{

   //Bussiness logic here
}
```

Comment: You need to take some time to understand the difference between Jersey and Spring MVC, and what you can use with each. They have no connection whatsoever and you should try and mix them, as it will fail.

Comment: @peeskillet , Actually i am having a working/live project based on spring-mvc and recently i had requirement to integrate swagger with spring. so i did some analysis and got know that using jersey i can enable swagger in my project and it works.

Comment: Spring MVC can do swagger. Look into [springfox](https://github.com/springfox). That way you don't need to try and learn a new framework (jersey)

Comment: spring-fox is asking me to upgrade my spring 3.x project to spring 4.x which is not do-able for me as of now.

Comment: I've never used springfox, So I don't know. But the thing is, if you want to use Jersey, you will need to pretty much refactor your entire application. Jersey is not something you can just add on top of Spring MVC. You either use Jersey or Spring MVC.